# Power Apps - Not able to render video from SharePoint Library into PowerApps Video Control

Tags: office365, powerapps, power-platform, microsoft365

Recently we ran into a scenario where the Video was not loading/rendering in the PowerApps Video Control. By digging in deeper we got to know that we have to login to SharePoint in a separate window to have the video rendered in PowerApps. Are there any settings/updates we need to do to remove this dependency of additional login into SharePoint?

This is how I am setting Media property of the Video Control:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share how you are setting the `Media` property of the Video Control

Comment: @SumitSingh - I have added a screenshot in the question that shows how I am setting Media property of the Video Control. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please check if you video or SharePoint Library or SharePoint Site is shared with everyone

Comment: @SumitSingh Yes, it is shared. This is not a permission issue. If I open SharePoint page in the next tab of the browser and refresh the Power Apps tab, the video gets rendered without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked straightforwardly without keeping my SharePoint Logged in. I set the `Media` property of my video control as below.

```
First(Filter(Document, 'Folder Path' = "Shared Documents/Video/")).'Link to item'
```

Here:

- **Document** is my SharePoint Default Document Library
- **Video** is a folder which I created inside Document Library and put my sample Video
- Using **First** to get the first item of my folder and extracting its link using its `'Link to item'` attribute

The only requirement is your **video** or **SharePoint Library** or **SharePoint Site** must be shared with the user who is opening/playing the video.